# Hall effect in a conducting ring

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, hall-effect

Consider a conducting ring moving through a uniform magnetic field of magnitude $B$, with speed $v$. To visualise, suppose the magnetic field is directed out of the page and the ring is moving directly 'up' the page. It has diameter $l$.

[image]

Now consider two points $a$ and $b$ on opposite sides of the ring, along its horizontal axis (i.e., if the direction of the ring's motion is along the $y$ axis, the points are along the $x$ axis). The question asks me to find the potential difference between the two points.

My question is, in the situation described above, could the Hall effect 'take place' (in a simplified universe, if need be)? I.e. could you argue that the free electrons in the ring are pushed to $a$ until a sufficient electric field is established? Or is the Hall effect limited to rectangular conductors?

As a follow up question, if allowed, how would you calculate the 'voltage around the ring'?

Any help would be appreciated.